# PATCH administrative users results in 503

Tags: php, permissions, microsoft-graph-api

I am synchronizing Contact-Information of the Office365 Users from a Database to Office.

Permissions are currently at least:

```
Directory.ReadWrite.All
User.ReadWrite.All
User.Read.All
```

Updating `mobilePhoneNumber` and so on works on all User-Objects except those with have administrative roles. There I get a 503 error.
It's a foreach of every User so there is no difference of the call.

I am using the PHP SDK:

```
$graph = new Graph();
$graph->setAccessToken($accessToken);
try {
    $graph->createRequest("PATCH", "/users/" . $userid)
          ->attachBody($updatearray)
          ->execute();
} catch(Exception $e) {
    print_r($e);
}
```

What am I doing wrong and how to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Maybe you can look here : [Microsoft Graph permissions reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference)

Comment: What is the value of `$updatearray`?

Comment: it is f.e. {"mobilePhone":"+49151xxxxxxxx","businessPhones":["+49821xxxxxx"]}